# Invalid JWT While Running External Function '{ "statusCode": 401, "message": "Invalid JWT." }

Tags: azure-functions, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Hi All I have created external function by following steps listed down by Snowflake

https://quickstarts.snowflake.com/guide/getting_started_external_functions_azure/index.html?index=..%2F..index#4

Also implemented JWT policy as specified in following URL
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/external-functions-creating-azure-ui-security-policy.html#create-a-validate-jwt-policy-that-allows-snowflake-to-call-the-azure-function

Getting following error '{ "statusCode": 401, "message": "Invalid JWT." }

Any clue what wrong i am doing.

Comment: What does the JWT decode from jwt.ms show? As in does it show the relevant claims in the token?

Comment: Yes @Srinath Menon  , it shows invalid code